# service --status-all freezes part way through displaying list

Tags: ssh, debian, service

debian 8.0, logged in over ssh

`service --status-all` freezes part way through displaying list of services

it gets to `ssh` and then doesn't display anything else and doesn't finish, it doesn't matter what I type in, it doesn't cancel it, i have to close my ssh client and log in again

Comment: I was having this problem, but was able to get around it by calling it with sudo. It *did* hang, at the same spot where it crashed before, but then continued on. Not a fix, but maybe a way to debug a problematic service?

Answer (score 0):

Real old Q&A, but I just had this problem on an old RHEL. The issue was that there was an invalid file /etc/rc.d/init.d. The file 'down' was somehow inserted by a curl command run from cron. When the file was deleted, `service --status-all` showed everything without a problem.